# Multi-Factor sorting of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, both have the same indices, however different values. What I want is a list of keys of the first dict sorted by the value. If there is a tie, the entry with the higher value in the second dict should be preferred. In both dictionaries, the higher value is better

Example:

```
node_degree = {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 2}
node_volumes = {1: 100, 2: 200, 3: 300, 4: 400, 5: 500}
```

I could sort the node_degree dictionary by value like this:

```
degree_list = sorted(node_degree, key=node_degree.get, reverse=True)
```

which will yield `[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]`. The entries 1 and 4 however have the same value (4), and in the second list `node_volumes` the value of node 1 (100) is lower than the value of node 4 (400). The same is true for the nodes 3 and 5. The result hence actually should be:

```
sortFunction(node_degree, node_volumes) = [2, 4, 1, 5, 3]
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sorts based on a tuple of the values from the first and second dicts:

```
degree_list = sorted(
    node_degree,
    key=lambda k: (node_degree[k], node_volumes[k]),
    reverse=True,
)
```

Comment: @Tom Dalton I'm kind of lost. I understand that the `lambda` is returning a tuple. But if we swap the values like `(node_volumes[k], node_degree[k])`, it completely changes the output. What exactly is happening there?

Comment: The "Key Functions" section of https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting probably explains it better than I can. Ultimately, our key function (the lambda) returns a tuple of (degree, volume) for each item (key) in the dict we are trying to sort. Tuples are sorted by python based on the rule "sort by first item. If first items match, sort by the second item. If second items match sort by the third item...", then the implicit order of these tuples is the ordering that the questioner wants.

Comment: I've finally understood how it works! The sorting is done based on tuples. When Python compares tuples, it only compares the first items in the tuples. Python will only compare second items when the first items of the tuples are same. The subtlety of this answer makes it so great!